# How to convert document from Letter format to A4 paper size in Latex?

Tags: pdf, paper-size, printing

All files generated by Latex are apparently set to letter size by default.

My service's printer only accepts A4-size paper.
Is there any way to force Latex to generate pdf files in A4 format?

I've already tried this using the following statement, but it doesn't work:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
```

Only when I use the following system does it work, it resizes the pdf to A4 and it works and I can print.

https://www.pdf2go.com/pt/redimensionar-pdf

Comment: Why do you set the option `total={6in, 8in}`? And please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work". What exactly is "it" referring to?

Comment: 6in by 8in is explicitly forcing it to be not A4

Comment: the default media size of your PDF (A4 or letter) is set when you install tex, but you can over-ride it using geometry `a4paper` option (and other methods)

Comment: Simply use the  `[a4paper]` option  for your document class.

Comment: @Bernard: That tells the LaTeX format that youa re using a4paper but it doesn't tell the thypesetting engine that the paper size is physically a4 paper. Using the `geometry` package does both BUT it also changes the type space (textwidth, etc.)  to be somewhat different. It's best to use the `geometry` package and also use it to set the textwidth, margins etc.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: I agree that geometry is much more powerful than a simple option for the document class, but as I understand the question, it was only about the paper size.

Comment: @Bernard that is what Herb is correctly saying, use of  `a4paper` in `\documentclass` does not set the paper size as reported in the PDF unless you also use a package that has backend-specific code (geometry, graphics, hyperref would all work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I didn't know that.  Thank you so much for the information.